# Concurrent object locks based on ID field

Tags: c#, locking

I have a producer/consumer process. The consumed object has an ID property (of type integer), I want only one object with the same ID to be consumed at a time. How can I perform this ?

Maybe I can do something like this, but I don't like it (too many objects created while only one or two with the same ID a day can be consumed and the lock(_lockers) is a bit time consuming :

```
    private readonly Dictionary<int,object> _lockers = new Dictionary<int,object>();
    private object GetLocker(int id)
    {
        lock(_lockers)
        {
            if(!_lockers.ContainsKey(id))
                _lockers.Add(id,new object());
            return _lockers[id];
        }
    }



    private void Consume(T notif)
    {
            lock(GetLocker(notif.ID))
           {
            ...
           }
    }

enter code here
```

NB : Same question with the ID property being of type string (in that cas maybe I can lock over the string.Internal(currentObject.ID)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, what do you mean when you say, "I want only one object with the same ID to be consumed at a time"?

Comment: How many consumers, and what's the distribution of the int ID values? Could you have, say, 32 locks, and take the ID modulo 32 to determine which lock you'll take?

Comment: @KMan, Say I have 2 object notif with the ID property being the same, I don't want the Consume method being executed for the two objects notif at the same time.

Comment: @Damien there is between 1 and 4 consumers, the ID are regularly distributed

Comment: I think you worry about performance prematurely, is this strategy impacting your performance is any noticeable way ? Do you take so many locks per second that the performance loss is noticeable? I think you should profile first. Anyway one optimization you probably should do is to remove they keys from the dictionary all locks have exited, maybe best accomplished using a weak reference dictionary.

Comment: @Pop Catalin, in fact I don't really cares about speed performance, I'm sure that this will work. I am less sure about the memory.

Comment: @Toto, memory is a valid concern, you need to release the objects using some mechanism, manual release on lock exit, using weak references, or some other form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As indicated in comment, one approach would be to have a fixed pool of locks (say 32), and take the ID modulo 32 to determine which lock to take. This would result in some false sharing of locks. 32 is number picked from the air - it would depend on your distibution of ID values, how many consumers, etc.

Comment: Yes, nice trick. But if it is suitable depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Yes - for instance, if all ID values == 1 modulo 32, then it's not so nice :-)

Comment: -1, Come on, this only reduces the threadrace probability by a factor, does not solve it.

Comment: @Pop - I mentioned already that there would be some false sharing. If you want to completely eliminate that, then go ahead - allocate 4000000000 locks.

Comment: @Henk - yes, that may work better if there's a skew to the distribution of ID values. If they're evenly distributed, then I'm inclined to a power of 2.

Comment: Pop, re the question: "too many objects created while only one or two with the same ID a day". Damiens idea solves that nicely. But only Toto can say how bad some false sharing is.

Comment: " ... then go ahead - allocate 4000000000 locks", the number of allocated locks is equal to the number of worker threads that lock on distinct IDs. (that could be just a few dozen or hundred or less)

Comment: Damine, such a large number would defy the purpose. I think this scales nicely from 10 to 1000 or so with a trade off between  memory and collisions.

Comment: While @PopCatalin is right, I don't really see any other solution here that are better (or have more votes) so I think this is a nice solution. Having a offset of 15 instead of 32 will be enough for me already.

Comment: @CularBytes, if using this method and have any kind of dependence between producers and consumers with different IDs, then it's a recipe for deadlocks ...

Comment: This is the same approach as what is used by [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TVal>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,745f1b5cae223ff4,references). While it is a collection that allow concurrent operations, it still has to lock sometimes and it use a pool of objects for that.

Answer (score 3):

Can you make your IDs to be unique for each object? If so, you could just apply a lock on the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>First off,

have you profiled to establish that `lock(_lockers)` is indeed a bottleneck? Because if it's not broken, don't fix it.</strike>

Edit: I didn't read carefully enough, this is about the (large) number of helper objects created.
I think Damien's got a good idea for that, I'll leave this bit about the strings:

Regarding

> NB : Same question with the ID
>   property being of type string (in that
>   cas maybe I can lock over the
>   string.Internal(currentObject.ID)

No, bad idea. You can lock on a string but then you will have to worry about wheter they may be interned. Hard to be sure they are unique.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the "Because if it's not broken, don't fix it." part. Why the intern idea would not work ?

Comment: Locking on a interned string would be a bad idea - you don't know if any other piece of code might be doing similarly. General rule is only lock on objects you own and control the lifetime and visibility of. Interned strings don't fit that.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to: Synchronize a Producer and a Consumer Thread (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(VS.80).aspx)

> In addition to simply preventing
>   simultaneous access with the lock
>   keyword, further synchronization is
>   provided by two event objects. One is
>   used to signal the worker threads to
>   terminate, and the other is used by
>   the producer thread to signal to the
>   consumer thread when a new item has
>   been added to the queue. These two
>   event objects are encapsulated in a
>   class called SyncEvents. This allows
>   the events to be passed to the objects
>   that represent the consumer and
>   producer threads easily.

--Edit--

A [simple code snippet](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2009/01/producer-consumer-architecture.html) that I wrote sometime back; see if this helps. I think this is what weismat is pointing towards?

--Edit--

How about following:

1. Create an object, say CCustomer that would hold:

   - An object of type object
   - And a bool - for instance, bool bInProgress
2. Dictionary that would hold

now when you check following

```
if(!_lockers.ContainsKey(id))
_lockers.Add(id,new CCustomer(/**bInProgress=true**/)); 
return _lockers[id]; **//here you can check the bInProgress value and respond accordingly**.
```

Comment: Could you at least add a small summary, just in case the link goes dead?  And that seems solid but not really faster than what Toto is doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a synced FIFO queue as a seperate class/singleton for all your produced objects - the producers enqueues the objects and the consumers dequeue - thus the actual objects do not require any synchronization anymore. The synchronisation is then done outside the actual objects.

Comment: This does not address the problem: There could be different objects with the same ID. Your queue would not prevent 2 of those to be consumed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning IDs from a pool of ID objects and locking on these?

When you create your item:

```
var item = CreateItem();
ID id = IDPool.Instance.Get(id);
//assign id to object
item.ID = id;
```

the ID pool creates and maintains shared ID instances:

```
class IDPool
{ 
    private Dictionary<int, ID> ids = new Dictionary<int, ID>();
    public ID Get(int id)
    {
    //get ID from the shared pool or create new instance in the pool.
    //always returns same ID instance for given integer
    }
}
```

you then lock on ID which is now a reference in your Consume method:

```
private void Consume(T notif)
{
       lock(notif.ID)
       {
        ...
       }
}
```

This is not the optimal solution and only offsets the problem to a different place - but if you believe that you have pressure on the lock you may get a performance improvement using this approach (given that e.g. you objects are created on a single thread, you do not need to synchronize the ID pool then).

Comment: I do'nt have the lead on the item's class